# Inserting data from SQL server into a RESTful API via SSIS

Tags: sql-server, rest, ssis, etl

I am investigating ways to move data from SQL Server into system exposed via a RESTful HTTP API.

If I were to use SSIS would I have to write a custom connector to push the data to the HTTP API after the transform step, or is there a built in feature that supports pushing to an HTTP API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to move a very small amount of data, you could use the [Web Services Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140114.aspx)
...but note that pushing data *out* of SQL Server is not what this task is intended for...

> The Web Service task executes a Web service method. You can use the
>   Web Service task for the following purposes:
>
> Writing to a variable the values that a Web service method returns.
>   For example, you could obtain the highest temperature of the day from
>   a Web service method, and then use that value to update a variable
>   that is used in an expression that sets a column value.
>
> Writing to a file the values that a Web service method returns. For
>   example, a list of potential customers can be written to a file and
>   the file then used as a data source in a package that cleans the data
>   before it is written to a database.

For more control, you'll want to look at using the Script Component in a data flow.  Much more flexibility/control.